# Matching multiple quoted strings in a single line with regex

Tags: regex, string

I want to match quoted strings of the form `'a string'` within a line. My issue comes with the fact that I may have multiple strings like this in a single line. Something like

```
result = functionCall('Hello', 5, 'World')
```

I can search for phrases bounded by strings with `['].*[']`, and that picks up quoted strings just fine if there is a single one in a line. But with the above example it would find `'Hello'`, `', 5, '` and `'World'`, when I only actually want `'Hello'` and `'World'`. Obviously I need some way of knowing how many `'` precede the currently found `'` and not try to match when there is an odd amount.

Just to note, in my case strings are only defined using `'`, never `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [^']+ between quotes:

```
var myString = "result = functionCall('Hello', 5, 'World')";
var parts = myString.match(/'[^']+'/g);
```

Comment: `[^']*`, in case the string is empty. (OP had `.*`).

Comment: Can you explain how this works? My understanding is that this will search for something that starts with `'`, then doesn't have one or more `'` between another `'`. How does that disclude the `', 5, '`?

Comment: it eats up a ', followed by a sequence of non "'" and the closing ', next it looks for the same expression, so it skips the 5 and scans until it find a new '. The /g flag is for global, meaning find all matches.
So, using your question, after the first match, it does not face (for further scanning) "', 5, '...." but ",5, '...."